# How to update uniforms in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, fragment-shader

I'm in the process of learning Three.js. Right now I'm adapting a shader that I made in Shader Toy to go on my own web page. It's a procedural terrain shader where the user can move around with the WASD keys. Currently, everything is working except for the movement. The position is declared in javascript as follows:

```
var pos = new THREE.Vector2(0, 0);
```

I update the value of `pos` with an event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
switch (event.keycode) {
    case 65: pos.x -= 0.25;
      break;
    case 68: pos.x += 0.25;
      break;
    case 83: pos.y -= 0.25;
      break;
    case 87: pos.y += 0.25;
      break;
    default: return;
}
});
```

The value is initially passed to the frag shader in the declaration of the shader material:

```
var shader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vs').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fs').textContent,
    depthWrite: false,
    depthTest: false,
    uniforms: {
        res: {type: "v3", value: resolution},
        time: {type: "f", value: 0.0},
        deltaTime: {type: "f", value: 0.0},
        frame: {type: "i", value: 0},
        mouse: {type: "v4", value: mouse},
        pos: {type: "v2", value: pos},
    }
});
```

and the updated value is passed to the shader in the second-to-last line of the `render` function:

```
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    if (canvas.width !== canvas.clientWidth || canvas.height !== canvas.clientHeight) {
        renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, false);
        camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth/canvas.clientHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        resolution = new THREE.Vector3(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, 1.0);
    }
    shader.uniforms['res'].value = resolution;
    shader.uniforms['time'].value = clock.getElapsedTime();
    shader.uniforms['deltaTime'].value = clock.getDelta();
    shader.uniforms['frame'].value = 0;
    shader.uniforms['mouse'].value = mouse;
    shader.uniforms['pos'].value = pos;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I don't know what could be going wrong here but I expect that it has something to do with the event listener since it's existence the only difference from the nature of all the other uniforms. Hopefully I haven't made a silly mistake, like I said, I've just begun learning these libraries.

UPDATE:

I tried instead taking input the same way I am with the mouse. i.e. adding a function to the js:

```
function readkeys(event){
    switch (event.keycode) {
        case 65: pos.x -= 0.25;
            break;
        case 68: pos.x += 0.25;
            break;
        case 83: pos.y -= 0.25;
            break;
        case 87: pos.y += 0.25;
            break;
        default: return;
    }
}
```

and then in the html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" onmousemove="readmouse(event)" keydown="readkeys(event)"/>
```

The shader was still unresponsive to keyboard input.

Comment: maybe [this could](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/bhbn1sb8/) help you

Comment: what exactly is happening? you don't have to assign the `pos` to the uniform every time, it's enough to pass it by reference once, and change the original.

Comment: @palihead Almost eveything is working: the sccene is being rendered as I expect it to be and the camera is reponding to the mouse being moved over the canvas. It's just that nothing at all happens when I press any keys, let alone WASD. Is that really so? I'm going to try it right now.

Comment: @palihead I commented out all the lines that update shader uniforms in the `render()` function and the scene was rendered as static. Is there something I don't understand about what you're saying?

Comment: @2pha That example doesn't appear to be using keyboard input, which is what I'm having trouble with. (maybe I didn't look at the code hard enough?)

Comment: `keydown` should be `onkeydown`. But, the canvas element does not fire keyboard events by default. Searching google for **canvas keyboard events** will yield many results on how to do it.

Comment: @2pha doesn't the `onkeydown` event occur only once when a key is pressed? I need an event that occurs continuously when the key is being pressed.

Comment: `onkeypress` may be what you are thinking of, but I'm not sure if it is continous. You would usually set up a loop (serTimeout or requestAnimationFrame) for movement, turning the loop on or off with `onkeyup` and `onkeydown`. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/paw4X/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `keyCode` not `keycode` in firefox.